# How do I loop my code through rows of variables in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, iteration, apache-poi

I am reading a 2D array from an Excel file. This array is read and created in a class `ExcelRead`.

My OTHER class, `SendAll` needs to loop using each row as a different set of variables. It will send an email for each row, which contains a unique "To" and "From" email. The logic for sending the emails is working, but I have the code in seperate classes for each email I send. This will be prohibitive when I have many email recipients. It would be better to store them in Excel rows, and have my code loop through and run the code for each row.

Basically, I need to loop through my `SendAll` code, running it for every row in the Array.

Here is my code for running each `Send`class separately. I.e. pulling only the specifically defined array values THIS email needs.

```
public class SendAll extends ExcelRead {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExcelRead newExcelRead = new ExcelRead();
    //newExcelRead.dataReader();
    String[][] data = newExcelRead.dataReader();


    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String port = "587";
    String mailTo = data[1][3];
    String mailFrom = data[1][4];
    String password = data[1][5];

(Below this is just my Send Email logic)
```

That's the important part, I'm not sure it will help, but below is my array class `ExcelRead`...

```
public class ExcelRead {

public String[][] dataReader() throws Exception {
File excel = new File ("C:/Users/(location)/Dashboards.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
int colNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
for (int i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
    //get the row
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j=0; j<colNum; j++){
            //this gets the cell and sets it as blank if it's empty.
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            String value = String.valueOf(cell);                             
            //System.out.println("Value: " + value);
            data[i][j] = value;
        }            
   }
//System.out.println("End Value:  " + data[2][0]);
return data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help.

```
ExcelRead newExcelRead = new ExcelRead();
//newExcelRead.dataReader();
String[][] data = newExcelRead.dataReader();

String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String port = "587";
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    String mailTo = data[i][3];
    String mailFrom = data[i][4];
    String password = data[i][5];
    // Send email logic.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is correct. I was just coming back to post the same thing, after realizing I had a pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like your first job is to transform this data a bit, you need to rationalise your raw array of data into just the unique to/from addresses. Here the To/From addresses form the unique 'key' to your data. For this reason I would suggest you change your dataReader to return a Map>. The key being the concatenation of the to/from addresses and the second element being the map of actual data. If your dataReader produced this it would be a lot easier for you to parse the data. I've not tested this but something like this, this assumes, like in your example that you know what data is in what columns.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
for (int i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
    //get the row
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    rowMap.put("to", String.valueOf(row.getCell(3, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));
    rowMap.put("from", String.valueOf(row.getCell(4, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));
    rowMap.put("password", String.valueOf(row.getCell(5, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)));

    data.put(rowMap.get("to") + rowMap.get("from"), rowMap);

   }
return data;
}
```

Now there are a lot of clever things you can do to create the Key value for your Map but that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your only problem right now is to send an email for every row while iterating through the **data** String 2D-array. Please comment if I am wrong.

```
int row = data.length;
int col = data[0].length;
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
{
    //write the email code here?
}
```